# Is git remote add the opposite of git clone

Tags: git, repository

With `git clone`, you basically download a repository from a remote machine onto your computer.

If you do `git remote add`, does that upload your repository to a remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

No, git remote add only define the path to the remote git repository.

If you want do upload the data do your remote repository you have to commit and push do server.

```
> git add .
> git commit -m "my commit"
> git push
```

See more at:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: OK, the push actually uploads it, but before you do that, you do a `git remote add` and that says where to upload your stuff?

Answer (score 0):

No, `git remote add` just adds remote repository and you do it only once.

Read more here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding-Remote-Repositories

Then, if you want to upload something to your remote repository commit changes and use `git push`.